# "Halving" neighborhoods in topological groups

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $S=B\left(0,\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)$ be a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Given a translate $S+t$, there is the nice property that, for all $x,y\in S+t$, we have $x-y\in S-S\subseteq B(0,\epsilon)$.  I would like to generalize this to arbitrary topological groups.

#### Fix a topological group $G$ with identity $e$.  For each neighborhood $U$ of $e$, does there exist another neighborhood $V\subseteq U$ of $e$ such that $\{vw^{-1}:v,w\in V\}\subseteq U$?

In the above, neighborhoods are assumed *a fortiori* open.

I have not assumed $G$ abelian, but feel free to do so if it changes the answer.

**Some observations on counterexamples**
The discrete topology is not a counterexample: take $V=\{e\}$.  Similarly, for the indiscrete topology, $V=U=G$.

One possible route is to look for an arithmetic obstruction.  $C_3$ is not a counterexample because it is discrete, but perhaps if $\{g:\nexists x(x^2=g)\}$ is dense in $U$, then there exists no $V$?  (One line of inquiry suggested by this nonexample is to considere $C_3^{\omega}$ with the product topology.)

Obviously, the argument for $\mathbb{R}^n$ goes through immediately if $G$ is locally metrizable.  By Nagata-Smirnov, that means that a (hypothetical) counterexample violates regularity, Hausdorffness, or $\sigma$-local finitude in $U$.

Checking Steen & Seebach for metrization counterexamples doesn't really help: most don't have a natural group structure.  The remainder are the Long Line (45), the converging rational topology (65), $\beta\mathbb{Z}$ (111), and the radial interval topology (141).  All of these violate metrizability by having neighborhoods of the origin that are "too large" (i.e. not $\sigma$-locally finite), but that's the wrong place to look.  If $V$ is large, then so is $U$.  Instead, counterexamples should arise from groups that are not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is almost immediate from the definition of a topological group.  The map $f:G\times G\to G$ defined by $f(g,h)=gh^{-1}$ is continuous (since the group product and inverse maps are continuous).  Since $U$ is a neighborhood of $e$ and $f(e,e)=e$, this means $f^{-1}(U)$ is a neighborhood of $(e,e)$.  That is, there exist neighborhoods $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $e$ such that $V_1\times V_2\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$.  The set $V=V_1\cap V_2\cap U$ then satisfies your requirements.